# Bug: Ctrl-Click on new "Welcome to Q&A for ... -- check out the FAQ!" does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed

Virtually all windows browsers support Ctrl-Click on a URL by opening it in a new tab or window.

StackOverflow sites normally support this for their URLs too.

Not so with the new banners that look like this:
`Welcome to Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers -- check out the FAQ!`
and
`Welcome to Q&A about the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites -- check out the FAQ!`

The "FAQ" on those banners looks like a URL, but is buggy.
In stead of letting the browser open the URL, it only executes some JavaScript that closes the banner, and opens the URL in the SAME window or tab, even if you Ctrl-Click on it.

Plain wrong web UI behaviour: if you manifest something as a URL to the user, it should behave like one.

The old banners (notifying about new answers, favourites, etc) used to work correctly.

--jeroen

Comment: It appears these 'new' FAQ things might not be new. Somehow, both StackOverflow and meta required a page refresh in order to understand my login-cookies this morning. Still: when you are not logged in, the banner behaves buggy; banners with 'changed favourites', 'new answers', etc behave correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smartest thing to do would be to have a proper `href="/faq"` for the link and only have the JavaScript function hide the banner.

Comment: Totally agreed; now I'm confused (because of the way meta works: answers that solve the underlying problem, are not always answering the question): should I accept your answer?

Comment: @Jeroen: it's entirely up to you, accept rate isn't really an issue on meta so it doesn't matter if you leave it open.  The only people who can provide a *real* answer are the SO dev team - and that may happen at some point.